# Java Reading large files into byte array chunk by chunk

Tags: java

So I've been trying to make a small program that inputs a file into a byte array, then it will turn that byte array into hex, then binary. It will then play with the binary values (I haven't thought of what to do when I get to this stage) and then save it as a custom file.

I studied a lot of internet code and I can turn a file into a byte array and into hex, but the problem is I can't turn huge files into byte arrays (out of memory).

This is the code that is not a complete failure

```
public void rundis(Path pp) {
    byte bb[] = null;

    try {
        bb = Files.readAllBytes(pp); //Files.toByteArray(pathhold);
        System.out.println("byte array made");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (bb.length != 0 || bb != null) {
        System.out.println("byte array filled");
        //send to method to turn into hex
    } else {
        System.out.println("byte array NOT filled");
    }

}
```

I know how the process should go, but I don't know how to code that properly.

The process if you are interested:

- Input file using `File`
- Read the chunk by chunk of the file into a byte array. Ex. each byte array record hold 600 bytes
- Send that chunk to be turned into a Hex value --> `Integer.tohexstring`
- Send that hex value chunk to be made into a binary value --> `Integer.toBinarystring`
- Mess around with the Binary value
- Save to custom file line by line

**Problem**:: I don't know how to turn a huge file into a byte array chunk by chunk to be processed.
Any and all help will be appreciated, thank you for reading :)

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: somewhere around 7GB

Comment: Look at [`FileInputStream#read(byte[] b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read-byte:A-). Then you can specify how many bytes to read at a time.

Comment: If im not asking too much, can you give some examples? or even a link to an example, i read it but im not sure how to implement it exactly. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To chunk your input use a FileInputStream:

```
    Path pp = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("logs", "access.log");
    final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024*1024; //this is actually bytes

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(pp.toFile());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
    int read = 0;
    while( ( read = fis.read( buffer ) ) > 0 ){
        // call your other methodes here...
    }

    fis.close();
```

Comment: Don't mention it. ;)

Answer (score 8):

To stream a file, you need to step away from `Files.readAllBytes()`. It's a nice utility for small files, but as you noticed not so much for large files.

In pseudocode it would look something like this:

```
while there are more bytes available
    read some bytes
    process those bytes
    (write the result back to a file, if needed)
```

In Java, you can use a [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) to read a file [byte by byte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) or [chunk by chunk](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[])). Lets say we want to write back our processed bytes. First we open the files:

```
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("input.txt"));
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.txt"));
```

We need the `FileOutputStream` to write back our results - we don't want to just drop our precious processed data, right? Next we need a buffer which holds a chunk of bytes:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
```

How many bytes is up to you, I kinda like chunks of 4096 bytes. Then we need to actually read some bytes

```
int read = is.read(buf);
```

this will read up to `buf.length` bytes and store them in `buf`. It will return the total bytes read. Then we process the bytes:

```
//Assuming the processing function looks like this:
//byte[] process(byte[] data, int bytes);
byte[] ret = process(buf, read);
```

`process()` in above example is your processing method. It takes in a byte-array, the number of bytes it should process and returns the result as byte-array.

Last, we write the result back to a file:

```
os.write(ret);
```

We have to execute this in a loop until there are no bytes left in the file, so lets write a loop for it:

```
int read = 0;
while((read = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
    byte[] ret = process(buf, read);
    os.write(ret);
}
```

and finally close the streams

```
is.close();
os.close();
```

And thats it. We processed the file in 4096-byte chunks and wrote the result back to a file. It's up to you what to do with the result, you could also send it over TCP or even drop it if it's not needed, or even *read* from TCP instead of a file, the basic logic is the same.

This still needs some proper error-handling to work around missing files or wrong permissions but that's up to you to implement that.

---

A example implementation for the process method:

```
//returns the hex-representation of the bytes
public static byte[] process(byte[] bytes, int length) {
    final char[] hexchars = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    char[] ret = new char[length * 2];
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int b = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
        ret[i * 2] = hexchars[b >>> 4];
        ret[i * 2 + 1] = hexchars[b & 0x0F];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation man :) but can you explain a little bit about that part that says "process(buf, read)". What exactly is process?

Comment: This is meant to be your processing function which "does something" with the bytes. I've added a example implementation which returns the hex-representation of the bytes.

Comment: This is stupid so  help at your own risk :) i tried assigning the values i got from buffer array to another array, it didnt work. Thanks for going out of your way to help man :) **Edit** dont help me with the stupid thing i mentioned earlier, ill figure it out

Comment: can you specify exactly how I can return byte[]