# java 8 splitting bytes into chunks

Tags: java, file, java-8, split, java-stream

I have to create a method where I need to chunk files into multiple bytes.

examples byte[] into List<byte[]> ,
lets say each of it is size 1 MB (sizeMB=1 * 1024 * 1024)

so 5.2 MB file should be list of five 1MB and one 2KB.
[2kb, 1MB, 1MB, 1MB, 1MB,1MB].

```
byte[] mainFile=getFIle();
List<bute[]> listofSplitBytes=getFileChunks(mainFile);

public void list<bute[]> getFileChunks(byte[] mainFile) {
    int sizeMB = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    // Split the files logic
}
```

I am trying to avoid adding, **if then else** ,to handle  . I am trying to find if there is a cleaner way to do it, like using streams or something like that?

Comment: this post may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399398/java-reading-large-files-into-byte-array-chunk-by-chunk/39399613

Comment: For large files, this will wreak havoc on your program’s memory usage.  Imagine reading a 500 MB file and having two copies of it in RAM.  A better approach is returning chunks one at a time as the file is read.  If that is not an option, put the main byte array in a ByteBuffer, and return slices of that ByteBuffer, so you aren’t duplicating the bytes.

Comment: Streams tag because, I wanted to look for some sort of functional programming solution.

Comment: I’m not exactly sure you what you mean by avoiding if/then/else.  You pretty much have to have a condition statement since you are truncating the first chunk rather than the last one.  You can use roundabout forms like `?`…`:` or Math.max/min, but one way or another, a conditional construct is going to be necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```java
public List<byte[]> getFileChunks(byte[] mainFile) {
    int sizeMB = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    List<byte[]> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < mainFile.length; ) {
        byte[] chunk = new byte[Math.min(sizeMB, mainFile.length - i)];
        for (int j = 0; j < chunk.length; j++, i++) {
            chunk[j] = mainFile[i];
        }
        chunks.add(chunk);
    }
    return chunks;
}
```

or if you want a functional solution, then try this:

```java
public List<byte[]> getFileChunks(byte[] mainFile) {
    final int sizeMB = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + sizeMB)
                    .limit((mainFile.length + sizeMB - 1) / sizeMB)
                    .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.copyOfRange(mainFile, i, Math.min(i + sizeMB, mainFile.length)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```